# dyld: Library not loaded on ipa objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my own app with my own framework.
The problem is I can build on my iPhone and simulator, but when I try to export the iPA and try to open the app I got this error.
using Zombie instruments app

I tried following things but still getting same error:

Cleaned, restart xCode, restart mac, pod update, Cleared derived data from xCode> Preference

Below error comes while running app :

> @rpath/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib

> Referenced from: //private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../Frameworks/....framework/...
> Reason: image not found

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed this library in your application. Go to application target where you added framework (which reported missing in error), in general tab go to `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`, spot missing framework. make sure it is has the option selected `Embed and sign` or `Embed without sign`. according to your requirement.
Refer the following image to locate settings:

[image]